# CF Image IP changing opacity and/or default size

Tags: php, size, opacity, wowza

I'm using this image ip generator from codefuture, which is giving me an image with the IP adresse.
I would like to change the Opacity and the default size of it as I'm using it as a watermark over a video. So I can't use css nore html or javascript resize and opacity.

Here is the PHP code:

```
    // Image color setup
    $outerBorder    = "000000"; // ob=b9b9b9
    $innerBorder    = "000000"; // ib=ffffff
    $leftFill       = "ffffff"; // lf=cccccc
    $leftTextColor  = "000000"; // ltc=555555
    $rightFill      = "000000"; // rf=dddddd
    $rightTextColor = "ffffff"; // rtc=555555

// on-the-fly color settings
//  <img src="ip.php?ob=b9b9b9&ib=ffffff&lf=cccccc&ltc=555555&rf=dddddd&rtc=555555" />

// image quality from 0-100
    $scaleQuality = 80;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Do not edit beyond this line

// get on-the-fly color settings
    if(isset($_GET['ob'])) $outerBorder     = $_GET['ob'];
    if(isset($_GET['ib'])) $innerBorder     = $_GET['ib'];
    if(isset($_GET['lf'])) $leftFill        = $_GET['lf'];
    if(isset($_GET['ltc'])) $leftTextColor  = $_GET['lt'];
    if(isset($_GET['rf'])) $rightFill       = $_GET['rf'];
    if(isset($_GET['rtc'])) $rightTextColor = $_GET['rt'];

// draw the image
    DrawButton($outerBorder,$innerBorder,$leftFill,$leftTextColor,$rightFill,$rightTextColor,$scaleQuality);

// Functions
function ImageColorAllocateHex($image,$hex) { 
    for( $i=0; $i<3; $i++ ) {
        $temp = substr($hex, 2*$i, 2); 
        $rgb[$i] = 16 * hexdec( substr($temp, 0, 1) ) + hexdec(substr($temp, 1, 1)); 
    }
    return ImageColorAllocate ( $image, $rgb[0], $rgb[1], $rgb[2] );
}
function getRGB($hex) { 
    for( $i=0; $i<3; $i++ ) {
        $temp = substr($hex, 2*$i, 2); 
        $rgb[$i] = 16 * hexdec( substr($temp, 0, 1) ) + hexdec(substr($temp, 1, 1)); 
    }
    return $rgb;
}
function DrawButton($ob,$ib,$lf,$ltc,$rf,$rtc,$sq){

    $font['image'] = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEYAAAAFCAMAAADPPGp0AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAAZQTFRFAAAA////pdmf3QAAAAJ0Uk5T/wDltzBKAAAAUElEQVR42myQgQoAMQhC9f9/+hh2TWUwmjxKIwAk4ZWj9ZWOepo1pSGBwbIx+PN+xsfGMpTt+zF72gaVvf21wVIUv2KzkdmIS5Cv25jfJ8AAoLwA7HynlYYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=';
    $font['xy']= array(46 => array("x"=>59, "y"=>0, "w"=>2),48 => array("x"=>53, "y"=>0, "w"=>5),49 => array("x"=>0, "y"=>0, "w"=>5),50 => array("x"=>5, "y"=>0, "w"=>5),51 => array("x"=>11, "y"=>0, "w"=>5),52 => array("x"=>17, "y"=>0, "w"=>5),
                    53 => array("x"=>23, "y"=>0, "w"=>5),54 => array("x"=>29, "y"=>0, "w"=>5),55 => array("x"=>35, "y"=>0, "w"=>5),56 => array("x"=>41, "y"=>0, "w"=>5),57 => array("x"=>47, "y"=>0, "w"=>5),73 => array("x"=>62, "y"=>0, "w"=>2),80 => array("x"=>65, "y"=>0, "w"=>5));

    header ("Content-type: image/png");
    $im = @imagecreatetruecolor(80, 15) or die ("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
    imagerectangle($im, 0, 0, 79, 14, ImageColorAllocateHex($im, $ob));
    imagerectangle($im, 1, 1, 78, 13, ImageColorAllocateHex($im, $ib));

    imageline ($im, 10, 1, 10, 12, ImageColorAllocateHex($im, $ib));

    imagefilledrectangle($im, 2, 2, 9, 12, ImageColorAllocateHex($im, $lf));
    imagefilledrectangle($im, 11, 2, 77, 12, ImageColorAllocateHex($im, $rf));

    $im = right2img($ltc,strtoupper('IP'),3,$font['image'],$font['xy'],$im);
    $im = right2img($rtc,strtoupper(getIpAddress()),(strlen($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])<15?15:12),$font['image'],$font['xy'],$im);

    imagepng($im,NULL,(9 - round(($sq/100) * 9)),NULL);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
function right2img($color,$text,$pos,$font,$fontxy,$im){
    $letters = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($font));
    $rgb = getRGB($color);
    $index = imagecolorexact($letters, 0, 0, 0);
    imagecolorset ($letters, $index, $rgb[0], $rgb[1], $rgb[2]);
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($text);$i++){
        $c = ord($text[$i]);
        imagecopy ($im, $letters, $pos, 5, $fontxy[$c]["x"], $fontxy[$c]["y"], $fontxy[$c]["w"], 5);
        $pos+=$fontxy[$c]["w"];
    }
    return $im;
}
function getIpAddress() {
    $check = array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP','HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR','HTTP_X_FORWARDED','HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP','HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR','HTTP_FORWARDED','REMOTE_ADDR');
    $ip = '0.0.0.0';
    foreach ($check as $key) {
        if (isset($_SERVER[$key])) {
            list ($ip) = explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Thanks in advance for helping me with this.
Antoine

Comment: why use a IP, its not a method of uniquely identifying anyone

Comment: Dagon, It's just to put a watermark over a video. Videos can be recorded by capture softwares so my client is asking me to put this kind of watermark. Doing it via wowza would transcode each videos for each visitor, which will use to much CPU. It's not the best secured option but it's onemore....

Comment: Have you tried searching Stackoverlfow for [video-watermarking] ?